# package-cleanup --cleandupes fails to remove duplicates

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, rpm

I have an issue with duplicate packages installed on my Fedora machine:

```
# package-cleanup --dupes
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
audit-2.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
audit-2.3.2-1.fc20.x86_64
dnf-0.4.11-1.fc20.noarch
dnf-0.4.12-1.fc20.noarch
firefox-26.0-3.fc20.x86_64
firefox-26.0-6.fc20.x86_64
firefox-26.0-5.fc20.x86_64
firewalld-0.3.9-1.fc20.noarch
firewalld-0.3.9.2-1.fc20.noarch
libvirt-client-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-client-1.1.3.2-1.fc20.x86_64
gnome-shell-3.10.3-1.fc20.x86_64
gnome-shell-3.10.2.1-3.fc20.x86_64
yum-3.4.3-129.fc20.noarch
yum-3.4.3-130.fc20.noarch
NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-25.git20131003.fc20.x86_64
NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-26.git20131003.fc20.x86_64
NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-24.git20131003.fc20.x86_64
```

When I try and resolve it, `package-cleanup` fails:

```
#package-cleanup --cleandupes
....see table of duplicates, confirm it ...
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-driver-network-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-driver-interface-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-driver-secret-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-driver-nwfilter-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
libvirt-daemon = 1.1.3.3-1.fc20 is needed by (installed) libvirt-daemon-kvm-1.1.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64
Complete!
(1, [])
```

How do I proceed?